# Group Aggregation performance in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a large amount of data captured by my apis, like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57446a89e5b49e297031fab8"),                   
    "applicationVersion" : "X.X.XXX.X",                 
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-05-16T23:00:00.007Z"),
    "identifier" : "v2/events/messages",
    "durationInMilliseconds" : NumberLong(14)
}
```

I want to group the whole collection by the identifier. So I use the aggregation framework

```
$group : {
    _id : {
        identifier : "$identifier"
    },
    count : {
        $sum : 1
    }
}
```

I have an index on identifer.

This is a simple count, i may want to work out average api response times and things like that, but the speed is putting me off.

On 7 million documents the aggregation takes around 10 seconds. If I do the equivalent group by in SQL on MSSQL it takes less than a second.

Is there a way I can optimize this type of aggregation or do I need to think about this differently e.g.

- changing how I collect the data
- use a different tool?

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB doesn't use indexes in aggregation framework except **$match** and **$sort** if used as first stage in aggregation framework. This is limitation and we can hope for improvement in future.

See [Pipeline Operators and Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes)  in MongoDB

Comment: I saw that, read the documentation and hoped I was missing a trick. I think I will have to capture my data differently to achieve the desired effect